# How to specify setprecision rounding

Tags: c++, floating-point

Can I specify setprecision to round double values when stream to std output?

```
ofile << std::setprecision(12) << total_run_time/TIME << "\n";
```

**Output:**
    0.756247615801

```
ofile << std::setprecision(6)<< total_run_time/TIME << "\n";
```

**Output:**
0.756248

But I need the output as `0.756247`

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is also `std::fesetround` from `<cfenv>`, which sets the rounding direction:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cfenv>

int main () {
    double runtime = 0.756247615801;

    // Set rounding direction and output with some precision:
    const auto prev_round = std::fegetround();
    std::fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);    
    std::cout << "desired: " << std::setprecision(6) << runtime << "\n";

    // Restore previous rounding direction and output for testing:
    std::fesetround(prev_round);
    std::cout << "default: " << std::setprecision(6) << runtime << "\n";
}
```

*(note that these are not the kind of comments I recommend, they are just for tutoring purposes)*

Output:

```
desired: 0.756247
default: 0.756248
```

**Important note, though:** I did not find any mention in the standard, that the `operator<<` overloads for floating types *have* to honour the rounding direction.

Comment: The only 100% correct solution so far, assuming a quality implementation where the functions to convert to decimal honor the rounding mode.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I added the part named `Important note, though`

Comment: @phreshel `fesetround` returns "Zero, if the requested rounding direction was successfully set.
Otherwise, a non-zero value": http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfenv/fesetround/#return I think you wanted to use: [`fegetround`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfenv/fegetround/) I took the liberty of editing your answer. Feel free to rollback if my edit doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JonathanMee: Whoops. I am perfectly okay with your perfectly valid edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the result of your division by a million, convert to an integer, and divide by a million (as a double). Have the side-effect that `std::setprecision` is not needed for the output.

Comment: +1 but, it obviously will not affect you in this instance, but always take care with this approach not to overflow your integer.

Comment: This will overflow only after 35.79 minutes (more precisely, if your integer is 32bit, you enter undefined behaviour (in practice most probably overflow) for total_run_time>=2147.5.)

Comment: Avoid the conversion to `int` (and the resulting possible overflow) by using `modf` (which breaks a `double` into its integral and fractional parts).

Comment: edit: some dirty trial and error bisection reveals an event horizon around 2147.483648000000130125

Comment: @phresnel I didn't mean the OP to multiply the time, but the result of the division. Clarified the answer. Oh, and of course the value you came up with would be `INT_MAX` divided by a million (and some rounding error).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes, the rounding part was what I wanted to exercise :) I upvote the new clarified variant

Comment: There is no need to convert to integer; the floor or trunc functions will provide the desired result without conversion.

Comment: Multiplying by 1000000 produces a rounded result, which can lose the desired rounded-down value.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to defeat the rounding by subtracting, in your second case, 0.000005 from the `double` before outputting it:

```
total_run_time / TIME - 0.000005
```

In many ways I prefer this as it avoids the potential for integer overflow.

Comment: But introduces possible rounding errors, since `0.000005` isn't exactly representable.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cout.write(std::to_string(0.756247615801).c_str(), 8);
```

It looks really dirty, but it works!

Comment: you could make it better and use `std::string::substring(0,9)`

Comment: std::string::substr creates an additional string object which is not needed, so I just used write to output the relevant part.

Comment: I just thought it would have better self-documentation, but you're right.

Comment: This solution has a double-rounding problem. The fewer additional digits are used in the initial conversion to decimal, the more noticeable the double-rounding problem is. There exists a number of digits for the initial conversion that means double-rounding is innocuous for all `double`s but I am not sure how many that is. This has something to do with the largest number of consecutive non-leading non-trailing zeroes there can be in the exact representation of a `double` in decimal.

Comment: This approach works in all cases, assuming a correctly rounded conversion to decimal, if 21 additional digits are printed. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20302431/139746