# C++ rounding behavior

Tags: c++, linux, g++, rounding

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    float f = 0.115;

    std::cout << f << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << f << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is:

```
0.115
0.12
```

It makes sense that 0.115 is rounded to 0.12. However, when we change f to 0.225 the output is:

```
0.225
0.22
```

Why isn't this rounded to 0.23?

Comment: Try and see what happens when you use `std::setprecision(20)` instead.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264681

Comment: [See](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even).

Comment: @n.m. Not relevant here; `0.245`, for instance, will round *up* to `0.25`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify setprecision rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264681/how-to-specify-setprecision-rounding)

Comment: @Frxstrem setprecision(20) shows 0.22499999403953552246. If I change from float to double: 0.22500000000000000555. I guess that explains it. Maybe I should be using doubles instead.

Comment: Don't just throw more bits into the problem.

Comment: @user974967 Using `double` instead of `float` will not solve the problem itself, you'll just get the same effect for different numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computer can't represent most decimal fractions numbers exactly, since it works with binary numbers. Instead, it tries to find the closest number it *can* represent, and use that instead.

For instance, my computer represents the following numbers as:

```
decimal      actual representation
0.115        0.115000002
0.225        0.224999994
0.245        0.245000005
0.335        0.335000008
0.445        0.444999993
```

By default, C++ will use normal rounding to closest, i.e., digits `5-9` are rounded up and `0-4` are rounded down. Therefore, of the numbers above, `0.115`, `0.245` and `0.335` will be rounded up to `0.12`, `0.24` and `0.34`, while `0.225` and `0.445` will be rounded down to `0.22` and `0.44`.