# Displaying Decimal Points In C++, Problems with Calculations

Tags: c++

I'm taking a C++ online class (probably a mistake) and I'm trying to figure out how to correct this code. I had to write a program from scratch and I'm totally stumped as to what I'm doing incorrectly.

This is what should come out:

> Blockquote  Welcome to name’s carpet calculator!

Enter the name of the room to be carpeted:  bedroom

Enter the length of the room in feet: 10

Enter the width of the room in feet: 10

Enter the price of the carpet per yard: 3.49

Enter the padding cost: 35

```
                                         Carpet estimate for bedroom
```

Total square feet of the room: 100

Total square yards of the room: 12

Total cost of the carpet needed:          41.88

Total cost of labor (at $6.03/yd):        72.36

Padding Cost:                                       35.00

Subtotal:                                             149.24

Tax:                                                        8.50

Total:                                                   157.74

> Blockquote

Some additional rules are: Square yardage for a room is calculated by dividing the total square feet by 9. Add 1 yard for any fractional differences.
The labor cost of installing the carpet is $6.03/yard
Tax rate is currently 5.7%

Here's my current code:

```
    // John Mayer Learning Unit 2 Assessment

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string roomName; // declarations
    int roomLength;  
    int roomWidth;
    int squareFeet;
    int carpetPrice;
    int paddingCost;
    int totalCarpetCost;
    const int TAX_RATE = .057;
    int laborCost;
    const int LABOR_RATE = 6.03;
    int squareYard;
    int subtotal;
    int taxCost;
    int totalCost;

    cout << "Welcome to John Mayer's Carpet Calculator!"; // displays this at the top
    cout << "\n\n What is the name of the room to be carpeted?"; // asks for the room name
    cin >> roomName; // stores the room name
    cout << "\n What is the length of the room (in feet)?"; // asks for the length
    cin >> roomLength; // stores the length
    cout << "\n What is the width of the room (in feet)?"; // asks for the width
    cin >> roomWidth; // stores the width
    cout << "\n What is the price of the carpet per yard?"; // asks for the price of the carpet
    cin >> carpetPrice; // stores the price
    cout << "\n What is the padding cost?"; // asks for the padding cost 
    cin >> paddingCost; // stores the padding cost **DOES NOT WORK**

    squareFeet = roomLength * roomWidth; // finds square feet by multiplying length and width
    squareYard = (squareFeet / 9) + 1; // finds the square feet and rounds up to the next yard
    totalCarpetCost = carpetPrice * squareYard; // finds the carpet cost by multiplying the input carpet price by the square yardage
    laborCost = squareYard * LABOR_RATE; // finds the labor cost by multiplying the yardage by the labor rate of 6.03
    subtotal = (totalCarpetCost + paddingCost + laborCost); // finds the subtotal by adding the labor cost, carpet cost, and padding cost
    taxCost = subtotal * TAX_RATE; // finds the tax cost by multiplying the subtotal by the tax rate of .057 (5.7%)
    totalCost = taxCost + subtotal; // adds the subtotal and tax to find the total overall cost


    cout << "\n Carpet estimate for " << roomName; // displays text and the room name

    cout << "\n Total square feet of the room: " << squareFeet; //displays the square feet calculation **CORRECT
    cout << "\n Total square yards of the room: " << squareYard; // displays the square yards calculation **CORRECT
    cout << "\n\n Total cost of the carpet needed: " << totalCarpetCost; // displays the carpet cost **INCORRECT
    cout << "\n Total cost of labor (at $6.03/yd): " << laborCost; // displays the labor cost 
    cout << "\n Padding Cost: " << paddingCost; // displays the padding cost 
    cout << "\n\n Subtotal: " << subtotal; // displays the subtotal
    cout << "\n Tax: " << taxCost; // displays the tax calculation
    cout << "\n Total: " << totalCost;  // displays the final total cost
    cout << "\n"; // line break


    system("PAUSE"); 
  return 0;


}
```

Comment: You should review what an int is and how integer arithmetic works.

Comment: I use everything the instructor provides. None of this was mentioned, but thanks for the shrewd response.

Comment: This is the line giving me a problem now:

cout << "\n Total cost of labor (at $6.03/yd): " << laborCost;

It's displaying 72 instead of 72.36 even after switching the variables to double instead of int.

Then I need to round down to 2 decimal places. I think I need to use "setprecision(2)" but I don't know how to actually put that into the code itself.

Comment: Okay, I added #include <iomanip> to the top and it looks like that fixed one of my problems, now I just need to know how to properly execute the decimal place constraints

Comment: put it before that `cout << "total cost of labor..."`

Comment: just a quick question you did change laborCost to double?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using decimals then you need to use `double` instead of `int`. A `double` is a floating point type. An `int` (integer) is a whole number and a number that is not a fraction. Therefore, using `int` for decimal won't work

```
int a = 1.22;
cout << a << endl;
//this will display 1
double b = 1.22;
cout << b << endl;
//this will display 1.22
```

because your compiler will use the whole number in front of the decimal not anything after it.

Comment: Awesome! That worked out and got the padding cost input to work properly. I have to round my calculations down to 2 decimal places which is the next issue, and my "total cost of labor" line is still showing 72 instead of 72.36

Comment: use `#include <iomanip>` `cout << fixed << setprecision(2);` < goes in main this will set the decimal place to two.[link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)

Comment: cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << "\n Total: " << totalCost;

This still displays 3 decimal places. I also switched squareYard back to int from double and it's displaying 12.1111 instead of 12.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the only issue is that the tax is off by a penny. I dunno why but it's close enough.

Final code:

```
    // John Mayer Learning Unit 2 Assessment

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string roomName; // declarations
    double roomLength;  
    double roomWidth;
    double squareFeet;
    double carpetPrice;
    double paddingCost;
    double totalCarpetCost;
    const double TAX_RATE = .057;
    double laborCost;
    const double LABOR_RATE = 6.03;
    int squareYard;
    double subtotal;
    double taxCost;
    double totalCost;

    cout << setw(15)<<""<< "Welcome to John Mayer's Carpet Calculator!"; // displays this at the top
    cout << "\n\n What is the name of the room to be carpeted? "; // asks for the room name
    cin >> roomName; // stores the room name
    cout << "\n What is the length of the room (in feet)? "; // asks for the length
    cin >> roomLength; // stores the length
    cout << "\n What is the width of the room (in feet)? "; // asks for the width
    cin >> roomWidth; // stores the width
    cout << "\n What is the price of the carpet per yard? "; // asks for the price of the carpet
    cin >> carpetPrice; // stores the price
    cout << "\n What is the padding cost? "; // asks for the padding cost 
    cin >> paddingCost; // stores the padding cost (this didn't originally work because carpetPrice was int, not double

    squareFeet = roomLength * roomWidth; // finds square feet by multiplying length and width
    //squareYard = (squareFeet / 9) + 1; // (Original code before realizing a 3x3 room would not work correctly
    squareYard = squareFeet / 9; // finds square yardage
    if ((int)squareFeet % 9 != 0)  // if the remainder does not equal 0 after dividing by nine, then...
        {squareYard++;} // ...round up 1
    totalCarpetCost = carpetPrice * squareYard; // finds the carpet cost by multiplying the input carpet price by the square yardage
    laborCost = squareYard * LABOR_RATE; // finds the labor cost by multiplying the yardage by the labor rate of 6.03
    subtotal = (totalCarpetCost + paddingCost + laborCost); // finds the subtotal by adding the labor cost, carpet cost, and padding cost
    taxCost = subtotal * TAX_RATE; // finds the tax cost by multiplying the subtotal by the tax rate of .057 (5.7%)
    totalCost = taxCost + subtotal; // adds the subtotal and tax to find the total overall cost
    cout << "\n\n" << setw(20) << "" << "Carpet estimate for " << roomName; // displays text and the room name

    cout << "\n\n Total square feet of the room: " << squareFeet; //displays the square feet calculation **CORRECT
    cout << "\n\n Total square yards of the room: " << squareYard; // displays the square yards calculation **CORRECT
    cout << "\n\n\n Total cost of the carpet needed: " << totalCarpetCost; // displays the carpet cost **INCORRECT
    cout << "\n\n Total cost of labor (at $6.03/yd): " << laborCost; // displays the labor cost 
    cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << "\n\n Padding Cost: " << paddingCost; // displays the padding cost 
    cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << "\n\n\n Subtotal: " << subtotal; // displays the subtotal
    cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << "\n\n Tax: " << taxCost; // displays the tax calculation
    cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << "\n\n Total: " << totalCost; // displays the final total cost
    cout << "\n\n"; // line break


    system("PAUSE"); 
  return 0;


}
```

Comment: you can fix that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264681/how-to-specify-setprecision-rounding) another thing you don't need to use setprecision(2) more than once. Because when you do setprecision once it will automatically do it for all the other one's below it. you can see this [here](http://cpp.sh/6a7m)

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's not actually my final code, I removed it once I realized that declaration holds true until it has been changed :P

Thanks again for the assistance!