# Why is not the output precision being rounded correctly?

Tags: c++, precision

I have tested the following code to verify some simple numerical outputs when `std::setprecision` is used in C++:

```
double f1 = 3.1415;
std::cout << std::setprecision(4) << f1 << '\n';
double f2 = 1.2345;
std::cout << std::setprecision(4) << f2 << '\n';
```

The corresponding outputs are:

```
3.142
1.234
```

Why is 1.234 not being rounded to 1.235?  Furthermore, if we change `f2` to 1.2315, then the rounding in the output does happen, and the output is 1.232.  Is there any rule of thumb to follow when using `setprecision` to format the output of numeric values?

Comment: `f2` is probably actually represented by `1.234499999999` or something like that, so it gets rounded down.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It does makes sense if `f2` is represented as you noted!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: I think an odd digit followed by 5 gets rounded up, while an even digit gets rounded down

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264681/how-to-specify-setprecision-rounding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment tells you why. I strongly recommend to read https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

In order to do correct rounding, C++ comes with [round()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/) for that but it only round to integer, not arbitrary decimal places. The following can give you `1.235`, although a bit ugly:

```cpp
double f1 = 3.1415;
std::cout << std::setprecision(4) << round(f1*1000)/1000 << '\n';
double f2 = 1.2345;
std::cout << std::setprecision(4) << round(f2*1000)/1000 << '\n';
```